# Is there a better way I can structure my tables, do a 4 table join, or will I have to perform multiple queries?

Tags: sql, postgresql

What is the correct way to perform this GET request? I currently have 4 tables:

events, event_comments, event_photos, event_users_going

The last 3 tables, event_comments, event_photos, and event_users_going all have a foreign key that uses  events table's  primary key.

What I am unsure about is, would I have to do a JOIN on all 4 tables or 4 individual queries? Because, each query on each table returns a different number of rows.

For example the **first query** would be on events:

```
SELECT * FROM events where e_id = 1
```

this returns 1 row.

**The 2nd query:**

```
SELECT * FROM event_photos where e_id = 1
```

this returns 12 rows

**3rd Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM event_comments WHERE e_id = 1
```

this returns 20 rows

**4th Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM event_users_going WHERE e_id = 1
```

this returns 30 rows

Comment: Four queries might be the best approach, because each query is returning different columns and different numbers of rows.

Comment: What is the result that you are actually looking for? Please provide sample data and expected results.

Comment: `The last 3 tables, event_comments, event_photos, and event_users_going all have a foreign key that uses events table's primary key.` Please use DDL, not text to explain your table structures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what is receiving the results. If it can process JSON and the overhead of doing so isn't a deal-breaker, you can do the following to include related rows as JSON arrays:

```
SELECT *,
       COALESCE((
         SELECT json_agg(event_photos)
           FROM event_photos
          WHERE event_photos.e_id = events.e_id
       ), '[]') AS photos,
       COALESCE((
         SELECT json_agg(event_comments)
           FROM event_comments
          WHERE event_comments.e_id = events.e_id
       ), '[]') AS comments,
       COALESCE((
         SELECT json_agg(event_users_going)
           FROM event_users_going
          WHERE event_users_going.e_id = events.e_id
       ), '[]') AS going
  FROM events
 WHERE e_id = 1;
```

Sample output:

```
 e_id |          photos          |        comments         | going 
------+--------------------------+-------------------------+-------
    1 | [{"e_id":1,"url":"p1"}, +| [{"e_id":1,"txt":"c1"}] | []
      |  {"e_id":1,"url":"p2"}]  |                         | 
(1 row)
```

When returning JSON, you can take it a step further and build a result with a single column:

```sql
SELECT json_build_object(
         'event', events,
         'photos', COALESCE((
           SELECT json_agg(event_photos)
             FROM event_photos
            WHERE event_photos.e_id = events.e_id
         ), '[]'),
         'comments', COALESCE((
           SELECT json_agg(event_comments)
             FROM event_comments
            WHERE event_comments.e_id = events.e_id
         ), '[]'),
         'going', COALESCE((
           SELECT json_agg(event_users_going)
             FROM event_users_going
            WHERE event_users_going.e_id = events.e_id
         ), '[]')
       )
  FROM events
 WHERE e_id = 1;
```

Sample output:

```
                              json_build_object                               
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"event" : {"e_id":1}, "photos" : [{"e_id":1,"url":"p1"},                   +
  {"e_id":1,"url":"p2"}], "comments" : [{"e_id":1,"txt":"c1"}], "going" : []}
(1 row)
```

Comment: Postgres is relational database -> the joins on well normalized tables will be significantly faster (10x times and more) than operations on json types. Using non atomic types should be only when it is necessary - due low structured data without possible normalization. In simple cases it can be used only from study reasons.

Comment: Agreed. Tables should stay normalized. Building JSON like this increases CPU load and memory usage on the database server.

Answer (score 2):

Joins are costly and can lead to redundant data as well leaving the total count of rows much greater than actual sum of rows obtained by your above 4 queries.

Therefore, you must use these 4 seperate queries as they also contain different data as youve already mentioned above